# Is there a way to delete initial column value when making a brand new list?

Tags: list, custom-list, column

When creating a new list for the very first time within SharePoint, you may notice that the first column that gets automatically created is "Title".

Is there a way to delete this column? I notice there isn't a "delete" button where it usually is for other custom columns that you create and then can delete later.

Answer (score 2):

Title gets created by default for all lists and libraries. If it is not necessary, it can be renamed to something more contextual to what your list or library is going to store. It isn't recommended to be deleted.

Comment: Is there a particular reason as to why it "isn't recommended to be deleted"? The reason why I ask is because I created a list page for my team in our SharePoint, and my team took the liberty to rename columns/create new columns and there is now one column that is called "PLEASE DELETE THIS COLUMN" that I suspect is the original "Title" column because there is no delete button for it.

Comment: Search heavily weights the title column when computing rankings. Deleting it makes it difficult to get the edit control block back. It is best to rename it than remove it.

Comment: Also, the title field is used for the subject of standard alerts. If you use alerts on lists, then those emails will become almost useless. What I do is make sure the title field is set to hidden, and give it a default value of something so those emails will have something to use as a subject.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to get "rid" of the Title column, go into advanced settings and allow the use of content type, then you can create a new content type or use the default document and have the option to hide the title field.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must, here is a reference:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28005/To-remove-the-title-column-from-a-Sharepoint-list

But as both above mentioned, I would advise not too.

You could also just hide it:
http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/how-hide-title-column-sharepoint-list-or-library